# How to load a string type .txt file into a heap data structure in java?

Tags: java

First, I am a beginner. My teacher gave me a homework and told me exactly this:

> "Your program will accept 1 file as input.
>   Each line consists of 1 string(name).
>   Your program will load all the names into a Heap data structure.
>   Then you will load the same file into a Set data structure.
>   Then you will load the same file into a LinkedList datastructure.
>   Print how long each loading takes."

From this, I understand that I need to load a .txt file into a heap data which has a few string(name) at a line. But I cannot find anything about loading a string type txt file into a heap data.

Which kind of heap data structure should I use? and how can I load that file into that heap data? Can you guys give me some recommendation please... Or am I misunderstanding the homework?

Comment: you can use PriorityQueue for heap. To load data you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868528/5313017

Comment: The PriorityQueue is implemented using a binary heap. Edit: You probably want to read the file line by line, then push it onto the heap. Good luck.

Comment: Let me google that for you: https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=java+load+text+file+into+set&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=java+load+text+file+into+linked+list&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english

Answer (score 0):

Use `Stack<T>`. This is a one-to-one representation of what you need (at least I assume so because there is no class named `Heap<T>`)
Use `.push` and `.pop` methods to add and remove items from the stack and just add the strings on a line-by-line basis.